# Django Management Command - reading file

Tags: python, django

I'm using the Django management command structure as follows:

with an example.py file saved here:

application_root/app/management/commands/example.py

example.py attempts to open up a file located here:

> application_root/app/subdirectory_1/subdirectory2/example.csv

The following code snippet is in the Command class in example.py

```
filepath = '/projects/myproject/application_root/app/subdirectory_1/subdirectory2/example.csv'
csvfile = open(file_path)
reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in csvfile), delimiter="\t")
for row in reader:
   print row
```

and is run as follows ./manage.py example.py
both management and commands have `__init__.py` files

nothing prints out for the rows.

when I run the same code from a test.py file in subdirectory2 it works perfectly just by using python test.py.

Not sure why.

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't closing the file prior to "reopening" it so the file pointer was still at the end.